# magic records being deleted

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

i have customised oscommerce to pull in a csv file of products, delete anything thats not with an image/proper description/proper title gets removed.

The import runs on a cron job basis pulling information from a supplier, it hasnt run since yesterday but a product has disappeared-

Anyone who has used oscommerce will know that, product information is stored over multiple tables. example is-

products
product_description

and so on. the thing that has got me that the information is deleted from the product table but not from the product_description table.

The product that is being deleted is a manually input one which carries a special tag/prefix on the model item of the product table. Therefore shouldn't be touched at all. Am clueles as what is going on.

Is there mysql integrity checks deleting records? could there be another plugin working on oscommerce?

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify 'magic' rows in your table you could create a BEFORE DELETE trigger on that table to check the row someone is planning to delete isn't one of them, and raising an error if it is. I haven't created a trigger for quite a while so I forget the syntax, but there's more about triggers here... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html